# Writing a dockerfile containing a custon mysql installation

Tags: mysql, docker, debian, dockerfile

I want to write a dockerfile where I install a custom mysqlserver with user + password.

My command looks like this at the moment:

```
RUN apt-get install -y mysql-server \
    -y mysql-client
```

can I specify the input vars as running parameter of the

docker build process?

Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so user2915097 has mentioned a nice option to you, but if you still want to create a separate image, you might proceed with the following pointers.

1. Figure out how to install mysql using a bash script (No manual input needed). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806037/install-mysql-5-7-purely-from-bash-script-on-ubuntu) link might help.
2. In Dockerfile, either run that script in Dockerfile itself, *or* save the script seperatly -> use COPY to copy it in the docker image ->  run the script using a Dockerfile instruction in container.

I think this is all you need to work on for now.

Answer (score 2):

have a look at the reference

https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/

I would rather begin my Dockerfile with

`FROM mysql`

or such .You can find on the previous link

`$ docker run --name some-mysql -v /my/custom:/etc/mysql/conf.d -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:tag`

which should meet your needs

Comment: but in this case I have to use the mysql docker image? ... thats not what I want. I want a clean debian image. and install a normal mysql server

Comment: as you want, but if you look at the Dockerfile of the reference mysql at https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/b4b7c8eea0690d0406a5ffc2d3404c8c42457a2d/5.6/Dockerfile , it starts with `FROM debian:jessie` :-)

Comment: if you want something "cleaner" you can use a mysql built from Alpine which is lighter than Debian, see for example https://hub.docker.com/r/wangxian/alpine-mysql/

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I need a full debian dist